# Is there any amateur way to process fabric into cellulose?

Tags: decomposition

[This article](https://www.lunduniversity.lu.se/article/watch-recycled-cotton-becomes-new-fabric) interests me.

It says they can decompose fabric into more pure materials - cellulose, then splitting that polymer/polysaccharide into glucose - by soaking it in sulfuric acid.

I read that sulfuric acid is highly dangerous to work with, because it harms human tissue and also is harmful if inhaled.

So, acids are positively charged, so they attract electrons from nearby molecules, which weakens those molecule’s molecular bonds?

Is there a different naturally occurring acid that can also dissolve cellulose like this, for example, acetic acid distilled from vinegar?

Is there a common microorganism that digests fiber? Perhaps composting or enhanced biodegradation/bioprocessing could also convert fabric into usable new compounds?

What’s a feasible way for an amateur to try to break down or process fiber like these researchers have?

Answer (score 0):

[Cuprammonium rayon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuprammonium_rayon) does not require $\ce{H2SO4}$. However, the solution is still somewhat toxic, disposal is difficult, and it readily stains things -- careless rayon chemists have blue-black hands and clothes.

It does make a good classroom demo, though, when performed with care: rayon from filter paper!